# Пересоздается компонент, вызываемый Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, tinymce, react-router-dom

Есть     `<Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditorControl} />` (Пробовал и в свитч оборачивать, и без)
Сам компонент - Tiny Mce

```
`const fetchJson = async (url : string) => {
    console.log("WTF")
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let json = response.json();
    return json;
};

type TParams = {
    id?: string;
}
const EditorControl  = ({match} : RouteComponentProps<TParams>) => {
    const [template, setTemplate] = useState(new TemplateData())
    console.log("mid", JSON.stringify(match))
    useEffect( () => {
      fetchJson('http://myurl/'+match.params.id)
            .then(result => {
                setTemplate(result as TemplateData)
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    });
    //let tt = plainToClass(TemplateData, a);
    let tempText = template.value
     console.log(tempText)
    return (
        <div className={s.EditorPage}>
            <Editor
                value={tempText}

                init={{
                    className: s.Editor,
                    height: 830,
                    menubar: false,
                    plugins: [
                        'advlist autolink lis1ts link image charmap print preview anchor',
                        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                        'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'],
                    toolbar:
                        'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
                        alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
                        bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'

                }}
            />
        </div>
    );`
```

У меня происходит постоянное пересоздание компонента. Почему и как исправить?

Comment: потому что useEffect вызывается всегда когда происходит перерендер компонента. Тем самым получается так: `ajax ->rerender->ajax->rerender....` в useEffect добавляйте проверку загружены ли данные.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov без useEffect тоже самое. Так и должно было быть?

Comment: Да и вообще интересно, почему перерендер-то происходит постоянный?

Comment: Честно по тайп скрипту не подскажу, предлагаю создать голый компонент, с какой-нибудь версткой, и запихнуть ссылку на него в router и посмотреть (без параметров) Далее отследить редирект. Если его нет, то начинать по 1 свойству передавать туда. и когда начнет редирект срабатывать, то проблема будет обнаружена. Возможно где-то функция какая-то срабатывает, которая вызывает rerender

Comment: пробовал. Typescript тут влияния не имеет, т.к. даже без него это происходит. 
Я попробовал щас useeffect проверять, но из-за пересоздания компонента он сбрасывается...

Comment: UPD: @DmitriiSedov я только что запустился без коннекта к серверу. Нет пересоздания компонента, как и пустых запросов

Comment: значит, ошибка где-то в данном коннекте кроется.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov, вынесите, пожалуйста,в ответ свое первое сообщение) Я неправильно проверку втыкал. Сейчас все ок и работает

Comment: Добавил сообщение в ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так происходит потому что `useEffect` вызывается всегда когда происходит `rerender` компонента (получается аналог `componentDidUpdate`).
В результате получается так: `ajax ->rerender->ajax->rerender....` в `useEffect`  добавляйте проверку загружены ли данные.